# Why does Loading an <a> in a forloop take more time

Tags: python, html, xml

I have the following code:

```
{% for ep in eps %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ ep.0 }}</td>
    <td><a href="/mturk2/{{ ep.0 }}/" target="_blank">{{ ep.1 }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Timing it, it takes 2.4s to do 10,000 `fo`r loops. However, if I remove the `<a>` tag, it only takes 1.6s. Why does it take any more time to build this HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access `base_url` 10,000 more times.

edit: OP deleted from `href` reference to `base_url` name and it didn't change runtime.

Comment: I see. How long it takes to go through all 10,000 eps with loop that does nothing?

Comment: It takes about 0.9s with nothing there.

Comment: So I guess you have your answer: adding line which uses `ep` variable (`<td>{{ ep.0 }}</td>`) adds ≈0.7s, and adding another one `<a href=...`) adds another ≈0.8s. I'm guessing here that `<tr>` and `</tr>` lines use very little time compared to the other two (you can check it as well), since they do not access any variables.